# Sbt occurred an error because failed to install a dependency at first time though resolver was set correctly

Tags: scala, sbt

I added `resolvers` definition in `build.sbt` to use geotools like below.

```
 resolvers ++= Seq(
   "Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository" at "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/"
 )
```

I executed `sbt update`, it failed with an error.

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.media#jai_core;1.1.3!jai_core.jar

I tried once, it was succeeded.

After I deleted `~/.ivy2`, I tried it the same way and it was always reproduced on my environment. ;(

I want to know that why it was absolutely failed at first time and how can I succeed it at first time.

Ah, my environment is `Scala 2.11.11, sbt 0.13.15, JDK8` in this question.

And I noticed that first time `sbt update` never look the repo which was defined in `resolvers`.

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] javax.media#jai_core;1.1.3!jai_core.jar (0ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: javax.media#jai_core;1.1.3!jai_core.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

I added jai_core directly to my dependencies and it worked for me:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jai_core
libraryDependencies += "javax.media" % "jai_core" % "1.1.3"
```